# writing JSON with JSP

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json, list

You would probably do this automatically with some library. But I am new with Java and JSON and I need a quick sollution.

What I would like is to write down (echo) JSON out of a JSP file. So far so good, but now I have a list of objects. So I start a fast enumeration.

And now the question: how do I close the JSON array with `}]` instead of `,`? Normally I put a nill or null in the and.

Here is my loop:

```
 "rides":[{  
<% 
List<Ride> rides = (List<Ride>)request.getAttribute("matchingRides");
            for (Ride ride : rides) { 
%>               
 "ride":{     
     "rideId":"<%= String.valueOf(ride.getId()) %>",
   "freeText":"<%= freeText %>" 
   },                      

     <% 
     }
     %>   
}  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate using an `Iterator` instead. This way you can check at end of the loop if `Iterator#hasNext()` returns `true` and then print the `,`.

```
// Print start of array.
Iterator<Ride> iter = rides.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) { 
    Ride ride = iter.next();
    // Print ride.

    if (iter.hasNext()) {
       // Print comma.
    }
}
// Print end of array.
```

Regardless, I strongly recommend to use a JSON serializer for this instead of fiddling low level like that. One of my favourites is [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Just download and drop the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`. This way you can end up with the following in the servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("matchingRides", new Gson().toJson(matchingRides));
```

and the following in JSP:

```
${matchingRides}
```

or with the old fashioned scriptlet as in your question:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("matchingRides") %>
```

Comment: Thank, this is quick and dirty sollution i was hoping for. I wil try GSON on the next occasion. tnx also for editting...

Comment: OK. Rereading. This sounds really easy. I will try it now. Tnx again

Comment: I had to do this as wel: rightclick the Java project, choose Build Path and then add the GSON jar's as new Library.

Comment: Then you've wrongly chosen/prepared the project. It has to be a *Dynamic web project*.

Answer (score 5):

1.) Download and setup [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in your application container.
2.)

```
GSON gson = new GSON();
<%= gson.toJson( rides ) %>;
```

You'll save yourself time in the short run and long run if you avoid the path of insanity.